# Intellij debugger: true becomes false, what is going on...?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have this config class:

```
public class ShiroConfiguration {
  private final boolean enabled = false;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
      return enabled; // ****
    }
```

Obviously, the mistake is that I made the enabled flag 'final', so it can never be anything but false.

At runtime, I was trying to figure out why my config was not enabled, so ran the code in the debugger (in IntelliJ), with a break-point set on the starred line. The debugger showed that enabled had the value 'true', yet this method was definitely returning the value 'false'.

Why can the debugger see an incorrect version of the object?

I cannot comprehend how this is possible. Is it a bug in IntelliJ, or in the Java debugging interface?

==============

Here is what I see in the debugger at a breakpoint on the line that calls config.isEnabled():

[image]

Comment: 1. Some programs have bugs. 2. All debuggers are programs.

Comment: This seems like something to report directly to [JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FIDEA).

Comment: Have you checked in the debugger that the instance where you reach the break point is your class? Possible shiro is wrapping your configuration class in an other class, which probaly overwrites you.

Comment: Definitely my class, this one does not get wrapped by Shiro. It does get its values set by being read from a yaml file by jackson though. Still it looks like my class (ShiroConfioguration) and the same instance (@4650) is indeed the one that I am stepping into with the debugger.

Comment: The reason this field ended up being 'final' is that I ran an automatic code check in IntelliJ, to look for fields that could be made final, then applied the automatic fix. I did eyeball the code after doing this, but missed this one. A bit dangerous to use some of those automated refactorings.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't made any mistake in calling the method, i.e. called a method of different class, this definitely seems to a bug in the debugger. The debugger seems to be neglecting the `final` keyword in the program temporarily. Just try removing the `final` keyword for a moment, and see if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, when I remove the 'final' keyword the returned value is 'true'. Still wondering if its a bug in IntelliJ or the Java debugging interface (JDI).

Comment: @user2800708 so, without final keyword, the result is what you are expecting right?